# Lisp Interpreter written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, lisp, interpreter

I had a task to reduce my Lisp Interpreter from 400 lines to 120 lines. I was able to bring it down to 255 lines without including newline after every function. I'm not able to figure out where I can reduce the lines of code. I wanted a different perspective to my code probably a repeating pattern which i'm not able to find. What all improvements can I push to my code?

[GitHub](https://github.com/AkshayIyer12/lispInterpreter/blob/refactor/lispInterpreter_v3.js)

[Input file](https://github.com/AkshayIyer12/lispInterpreter/blob/refactor/newexample.txt)

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('newexample.txt', 'utf-8')
const ENV = {}
let mat, regexp = /^[0-9]+/, output
const spaceParser = (input) => (mat = input.match(/^[\s\t\n]+/)) ? [mat[0], input.slice(mat[0].length)] : null
const identifierParser = (input) => (mat = input.match(/^[a-z]+[0-9]*[a-z]*/i)) ? [mat[0], input.slice(mat[0].length)] : null
const numberParser = (input) => (mat = regexp.exec(input)) ? [parseInt(mat[0]), input.slice(mat[0].length)] : null
const stringParser = (data) => {
  if (data[0] === '"') {
    data = data.substring(1, data.length)
    let i = data.search('"')
    return ([data.substring(0, i), data.slice(i + 1)])
  }
  return null
}
const add = input => input.reduce((accum, value) => (ENV[value]) ? accum + ENV[value] : accum + value, 0)
const sub = input => input.reduce((accum, value) => (ENV[value]) ? accum - ENV[value] : accum - value)
const mul = input => input.reduce((accum, value) => (ENV[value]) ? accum * ENV[value] : accum * value, 1)
const div = input => input.reduce((accum, value) => (ENV[value]) ? accum / ENV[value] : accum / value)
const greaterThan = (a, b) => a > b
const lessThan = (a, b) => a < b
const greaterThanEqualTo = (a, b) => a >= b
const lessThanEqualTo = (a, b) => a <= b
const EqualTo = (a, b) => a === b
const notNumber = (a) => !a
const maxNumber = (a, b) => a > b ? a : b
const minNumber = (a, b) => a < b ? a : b
const listCall = (a) => { return { type: 'list', args: a } }
const listCar = (a) => a[0].shift()
const listCdr = (a) => {
  a[0].shift()
  return a[0]
}
const listCons = (a) => {
  a[1].unshift(a[0])
  return a[1]
}
const isListLisp = (a) => !!(Array.isArray(a))
const defineLisp = (a, b) => { ENV[a] = b }
const printLisp = (a) => (ENV[a]) ? console.log(ENV[a]) : a
const ifLisp = (a, b, c) => a ? b : c
const plusParser = (data) => data.startsWith('+') ? [add, data.slice(1)] : null
const minusParser = (data) => data.startsWith('-') ? [sub, data.slice(1)] : null
const mulParser = (data) => data.startsWith('*') ? [mul, data.slice(1)] : null
const divParser = (data) => data.startsWith('/') ? [div, data.slice(1)] : null
const greaterThanParser = (data) => data.startsWith('>') ? [greaterThan, data.slice(1)] : null
const lessThanParser = (data) => data.startsWith('<') ? [lessThan, data.slice(1)] : null
const greaterThanEqualToParser = (data) => data.startsWith('>=') ? [greaterThanEqualTo, data.slice(2)] : null
const lessThanEqualToParser = (data) => data.startsWith('<=') ? [lessThanEqualTo, data.slice(2)] : null
const equalToParser = (data) => data.startsWith('==') ? [EqualTo, data.slice(2)] : null
const maxParser = (data) => data.startsWith('max') ? [maxNumber, data.slice(3)] : null
const minParser = (data) => data.startsWith('min') ? [minNumber, data.slice(3)] : null
const notParser = (data) => data.startsWith('not') ? [notNumber, data.slice(3)] : null
const listParser = (data) => data.startsWith('list') ? [listCall, data.slice(4)] : null
const carList = (data) => data.startsWith('car') ? [listCar, data.slice(3)] : null
const cdrList = (data) => data.startsWith('cdr') ? [listCdr, data.slice(3)] : null
const consList = (data) => data.startsWith('cons') ? [listCons, data.slice(4)] : null
const isListIden = (data) => data.startsWith('isList') ? [isListLisp, data.slice(6)] : null
const defineSlicerParser = (data) => data.startsWith('define') ? [defineLisp, data.slice(6)] : null
const ifSlicerParser = (data) => data.startsWith('if') ? [ifLisp, data.slice(2)] : null
const printSlicerParser = (data) => data.startsWith('print') ? [printLisp, data.slice(5)] : null
const lambdaSlicerParser = (data) => data.startsWith('lambda') ? ['lambda', data.slice(6)] : null
const openBracket = (input) => (input.startsWith('(')) ? ['(', input.slice(1)] : null
const closeBracket = (input) => (input.startsWith(')')) ? [')', input.slice(1)] : null
const parserFactory = (...parsers) => (input) => {
  for (let parser of parsers) {
    let output = parser(input)
    if (output !== null) return output
  }
  return null
}
const allParser = (...parsers) => (input) => {
  let result = []
  for (let parser of parsers) {
    let output = parser(input)
    if (output === null) return null
    result.push(output[0])
    input = output[1]
  }
  return [result, input]
}
const operatorFinder = (input) => parserFactory(plusParser, minusParser, mulParser,
  divParser, greaterThanEqualToParser, lessThanEqualToParser, equalToParser,
  greaterThanParser, lessThanParser, maxParser, minParser, notParser, listParser,
  carList, cdrList, consList, isListIden)(input)
const operatorParser = (input) => {
  let count = 1
  if (!input.startsWith('(')) return null
  input = input.slice(1)
  if (input.startsWith('>') || input.startsWith('>=') ||
    input.startsWith('<') || input.startsWith('<=') ||
    input.startsWith('==') || input.startsWith('max') ||
    input.startsWith('min')) {
    count++
  }
  let output = operatorFinder(input)
  if (output === null) return null
  // For Operator Operand1 Operand2
  let result = [], vid = '', args = 'args'
  result.push(output[0])
  while (output[0] !== ')') {
    output = spaceParser(output[1])
    output = expressionParser(output[1])
    if (ENV[output[0]]) {
      (ENV[output[0]].args) ? result.push(ENV[output[0]].args) : result.push(ENV[output[0]])
    } else {
      result.push(output[0])
    }
    output = (vid = closeBracket(output[1])) ? vid : output
  }
  if (output[0] === ')') {
    if (output[1] === '') {
      return [evaluate(result, count)]
    } else {
      return [evaluate(result, count), output[1]]
    }
  }
}
const evaluate = (input, count) => {
  let operation = input.shift()
  if (count > 1) return operation(...input)
  else return operation(input)
}
const expressionParser = (input) => parserFactory(numberParser, stringParser,
  lambdaParser, identifierParser, operatorParser)(input)
const lambdaArgumentsParser = (input) => {
  let result = [], output
  input = openBracket(input)
  input = input[1]
  while (!input.startsWith(')')) {
    input = identifierParser(input)
    result.push(input[0])
    input = (output = spaceParser(input[1])) ? output[1] : input[1]
  }
  input = closeBracket(input)
  return [result, input[1]]
}
const lambdaBodyParser = (input) => {
  let count = 0, k = 0, output = ''
  do {
    if (input[k] === '(') count++
    if (input[k] === ')') count--
    output += input[k]
    k++
  } while (count !== 0)
  input = input.slice(k)
  return [output, input]
}
const defineLambda = (input) => {
  let obj = {}, count = 3
  let output = allParser(openBracket, lambdaSlicerParser, spaceParser, lambdaArgumentsParser,
    spaceParser, lambdaBodyParser, closeBracket)(input)
  if (output === null) return null
  let [[, Type, , Args, , Body], rest] = output
  obj.type = Type, obj.args = Args, obj.body = Body
  return [obj, rest, count]
}
const checker = (output) => {
  if ((output[0] === 'list') || (output[0] === 'max') || (output[0] === 'min') ||
   (output[0] === 'car') || (output[0] === 'cdr') || (output[0] === 'cons') ||
   (output[0] === 'isList')) {
    return null
  }
}
const lambdaParser = (input) => {
  if (!input.startsWith('(')) return null
  input = input.slice(1)
  let output = identifierParser(input)
    let type = 'type'
  if ((output === null) || (checker(output) === null) || (ENV[output[0]].type === undefined)) return null
  let key = output[0], arr = []
  while (!output[1].startsWith(')')) {
    output = spaceParser(output[1])
    if (numberParser(output[1])) {
      output = numberParser(output[1])
      arr.push(output[0])
    }
    if (identifierParser(output[1])) {
      output = identifierParser(output[1])
      if (ENV[output[0]] !== undefined) {
        output[0] = ENV[output[0]]
        arr.push(output[0])
      }
    }
    if (output[1].startsWith('(')) {
      output = lambdaParser(output[1])
      arr.push(output[0][0])
    }
  }
  let value = output[0], args = 'args', body = 'body', env = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    env[ENV[key].args[i]] = arr[i]
  }
  env[body] = ENV[key].body
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    env[body] = env[body].replace(ENV[key].args[i], env[ENV[key].args[i]])
  }
  env[body] = env[body].replace(ENV[key].args[0], value)
  env[body] = env[body].replace(ENV[key].args[0], value)
  output = (vid = closeBracket(output[1])) ? vid : output
  if (output[0] === ')') {
    return [operatorParser(env[body]), output[1]]
  }
}
const defineParser = (input) => {
  let arr = [], count = 1
  let output = allParser(openBracket, defineSlicerParser, spaceParser, identifierParser,
    spaceParser)(input)
  if (output === null) return null
  let [[ , defineFunc, , iden], rest] = output
  input = rest
  output = defineLambda(input)
  if (output === null) output = expressionParser(input)
  let [val1, val2] = output
  arr.push(defineFunc, iden, val1)
  count += 3
  evaluate(arr, count)
  input = closeBracket(val2)
  return input[1]
}
const printParser = (input) => {
  let arr = [], count = 1
  let output = allParser(openBracket, printSlicerParser, spaceParser, expressionParser,
    closeBracket)(input)
  if (output === null) return null
  let [[, printFunc, , exp], rest] = output
  arr.push(printFunc)
  ENV[exp] ? arr.push(ENV[exp]) : arr.push(exp)
  console.log('Evaluate to ' + evaluate(arr, count))
  if (rest === null) {
    return null
  }
  return rest
}
const ifParser = (input) => {
  let arr = [], count = 0
  let output = allParser(openBracket, ifSlicerParser, spaceParser, expressionParser, spaceParser, expressionParser, spaceParser, expressionParser, closeBracket)(input)
  if (output === null) return null
  let [[, ifFun, , test, , conseq, , alt], rest] = output
  arr.push(ifFun, test, conseq, alt)
  console.log('Evaluate to ' + evaluate(arr, count + 3))
  return rest
}
const statementParser = (input) => parserFactory(defineParser, printParser, ifParser)(input)
const programParser = (input) => {
  while (input !== '' && input !== null) {
    let spaceParsed = ''
    input = (spaceParsed = spaceParser(input)) ? spaceParsed[1] : input
    input = statementParser(input)
  }
  return ENV
}
console.log((output = programParser(input)) ? output : 'Error')
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it's explicit goal is not "good code"  but to reach the 120-lines restriction, which I consider bad research

Comment: Changed my down-vote to an up-vote, the quality of the answer it generated was very good, plus the connection to 'research' is tenuous

Comment: Most of the `if` statements could be turned into nested ternary-operator trees to get them on one line.  Also, having something like `k++` on its own line avoids the original intention of the `++` operator, which was basically to avoid needing a new line to iterate `k`.

Comment: Actually, if you're not concerned with efficiency, a sufficiently large function that's basically one huge ternary tree that recursively calls itself could probably one-line it.  That'd be a funny implementation to see.  =P

Answer (score 8):

### Expectations

Lisp is well-known for it's REPL, so I'd expect to see at least the following 3 functions in any Lisp interpreter: `read`, `evaluate` and `print`.

- `read` takes a string and returns a form (a number, string, symbol, list, and so on). For example: `read("(+ 4 5)")` should return a list that contains the symbol `+` and the numbers `4` and `5`.
- `evaluate` takes a form and evaluates it. Some forms, such as numbers and strings, simply evaluate to themselves. Symbols evaluate to whatever they're bound to. Lists are evaluated as function calls, unless their first item is a special operator - in that case it's a special form, which has its own evaluation rules.
- `print` takes a form and returns a textual representation of it.

### Main problems

Your code contains a *lot* of parsing functions. It's almost as if everything is a parser. There are a few standard functions hidden in-between (`add`, `sub`, and so on), and there's an `evaluate` function as well, but that appears to handle function application, not general evaluation of forms.

- Organize your code into separate parts. Those comment headers are helpful, but not enough. You may also want to hide most of those functions, as they're internal and shouldn't be part of the public interface of your Lisp interpreter. Currently there are no clear 'entry points' in your code.
- Make a clear separation between parsing and evaluation code. Several parse functions appear to do both parsing and evaluation, which is inflexible and makes them harder to reuse. Classes and functions should have a single responsibility.
- You've got lots of special-case parsing functions. Every operator and standard function has a matching parser function. Why? In Lisp, `+` and `-` are just symbols that are bound to standard 'add' and 'subtract' functions. The same goes for special forms: for the parser, they're just symbols. You only need a single symbol-parsing function.
- You've got a `parserFactory` function that calls several parser functions in a row, until one of them returns a non-null result. I think this has the following problems:

  - It's more difficult to determine control flow.
  - It causes more work to be done than necessary, because each parse function needs to do some work before it finds out whether the input is valid or not.
  - It requires more code, because each parse function needs additional checks.
  - It's also more error-prone, because a failure in any parse function can cause problems. For example, `(print (if (== 1 1) 4 5))` fails due to a check in `lambdaParser` - even though there's no lambda in that input at all.
- An interpreter is usually stateful - it needs to store things in memory. You're using a global `ENV` variable for that. That means that you can have only one interpreter at the same time. If your interpreter is a 'class', other code could instantiate it and have as many or as few independent interpreters as needed.
- It looks like your code doesn't actually work very well. For example, it chokes on the sample code by ending up in an infinite loop.

These points alone should be sufficient for a major overhaul. Addressing them will likely also reduce the amount of code. That may well be the reason why you were told to do this in less code: to force you to come up with a better approach. Having less code is beneficial, but shouldn't be a goal all by itself.

### Other issues

- Most function names here are nouns. Verbs would be more appropriate. `parseExpression(input)` looks more natural than `expressionParser(input)`.
- Use clear and descriptive names. `spaceParser` doesn't parse spaces, it skips spaces, so `skipSpaces` would be a better name. Your `evaluate` function performs function application, so it's better named as `apply` or `applyFunction`.
- Javascript isn't statically typed, which can make it easier to work with, but it also makes code less self-documenting. You may want to document that those parse functions return a `[value, rest-of-input]` array.
- Returning the rest of the input as a string requires a lot of strings to be created. This may cause performance issues for large inputs.
- You're working on a Lisp interpreter, so use Lisp terminology (and use it correctly): symbols, forms, special forms, function application, evaluation, and so on. Using different terms or using them with a different meaning makes your code much harder to understand.
- Putting if/else bodies on the same line makes code less readable. It may reduce the number of code *lines*, but it doesn't reduce the overall amount of code.

There is probably more that can be said about this, but I'll stop here.

EDIT: Inspired by Konijn, I've written down how I would approach this.

### Recommendations

Here's what I would do:

First, come up with a way to store your Lisp programs in memory. The easiest way is probably to just use Javascript booleans, numbers, strings and lists, and a few classes for symbols and functions defined in Lisp. Once you've got that worked out, you know what `read` should return, and what `evaluate` and `print` should work with.

---

To implement `read`, a few helper functions for parsing lists, symbols, strings and numbers (and perhaps other things) will be useful. These functions should be easy to test in isolation:

- `parseString('"hello world"')` should return the (Javascript) string `'hello world'`
- `parseNumber('14.5')` should return the (Javascript) number `14.5`
- `parseSymbol('is-empty?')` should return the result of `new LispSymbol('is-empty?')`
- `parseList('(+ 4 (* 2 5))')` should return the equivalent of `[new LispSymbol('+'), 4, [new LispSymbol('*'), 2, 5]]`.
- A general `parseForm` function that inspects its input and calls one of the above functions should also be useful. Not only as an entry point, but `parseList` can also use it to parse its elements (which makes it recursive, and capable of parsing nested lists and lists with arbitrary content).

Don't forget to come up with a good error-handling strategy.

---

Implementing `print` should be fairly straight-forward. Just check the type of the given Lisp form, and return a string representation of it:

- `print(4)` -> `4`
- `print('hello')` -> `"hello"`
- `print([4, [5, 6]])` -> `'(4 (5 6))`
- `print(new LispSymbol('my-variable'))` -> `'my-variable`
- `print(new LispFunction('add', ...))` -> `#<function:add>`

and so on.

---

`evaluate` is where the real work happens. As with `print`, it needs to check the type of the given Lisp form, and handle each type accordingly:

- Primitives like booleans, numbers, strings and functions evaluate to themselves, so they can be returned directly.
- Symbols evaluate to the result of a lookup in the current execution context.
- Lists are either function applications or special forms:

  - If the first element is a special syntax symbol (a keyword, if you will) then special rules apply (depending on the keyword). You typically end up with a separate evaluation function for each special form - usually a dozen or two, depending on how complete you want your Lisp to be.
  - For function applications, the first element of the list must evaluate to a function, and the rest of the elements are then evaluated and used as arguments for the function call. You'll probably have to handle standard functions (such as `+`, `-`, and so on) and Lisp functions (the result of a `define`) separately, because the former are Javascript functions under the hood, and the latter are `LispFunction` objects whose function bodies must be evaluated. You could wrap those standard functions in `NativeFunction` objects and give both the same interface to simplify things.
  - Or they're macro calls. Macros are functions that return code, and they're usually expanded after reading and before evaluation. What requires a compiler extension in other languages can often be done with macros in Lisp.

---

I've probably overlooked a few things, and there are of course many more details to figure out, depending on how simple or complex you want your interpreter to be. Feel free to ask for another code review once you've improved your code.

Comment: Very interesting read, if you have more to say/write, then I would love to read it.

Comment: @konijn: thanks! You inspired me to add some recommendations. :)

Comment: I didn't try intermediary invoked expression functions because I wasn't familiar with the concept. This was my final code https://github.com/AkshayIyer12/lispInterpreter/blob/master/lispInterpreter_v3.js

Comment: @AkshayIyer: I don't know if you've seen the recommendations I added, but give them a try. You should be able to significantly reduce the amount of parsing code (there is no special parsing required for operators or special forms!), and the evaluation code should also be easier to implement correctly. Your `if`, for example, evaluates both of its last two 'arguments' - but it should only evaluate one of them, because it's a 'special form', not an ordinary function. That's probably difficult to fix with your current approach, because your parse functions also perform evaluation.

Comment: Yeah I didn't check recommendation. I sure want to give it a try to make a better interpreter.